# filter data based on month on mysql

Tags: mysql-workbench

i just want to know the data who only appear in month apr - june 2018, and ignore the data who appear in month before that, idk why the result is 0 instead when i check manual on random data, it is exist. here's my syntax

SELECT DISTINCT
    d1.buyer_id,
    d1.tgl
FROM data_2018 d1
INNER JOIN data_2018 d2
    ON d1.buyer_id = d2.buyer_id
INNER JOIN data_2017 d3
    ON d1.buyer_id = d3.buyer_id
WHERE
    MONTH(d1.tgl) IN (4, 5, 6) AND
    MONTH(d2.tgl) NOT IN (1, 2, 3) AND
    MONTH(d3.tgl) NOT IN (1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I recommend using date literals to specify the date range you want.  Also, I suggest using `EXISTS` logic here:

```
SELECT DISTINCT
    d1.buyer_id,
    d1.tgl
FROM data_2018 d1
WHERE
    d1.tgl >= '2018-04-01' AND d1.tgl < '2018-07-01' AND
    NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM data_2018 d2
                WHERE d2.buyer_id = d1.buyer_id AND d2.tgl < '2018-04-01');
```

This assumes that you only want to eliminate records which also appear *before* April 2018.  If you also want to restrict to not appearing *after* June 2018, then we would need to add a check for that to the `EXISTS` subquery.

Comment: what's the function of select 1 of your query sir?

Comment: @FachryDzakyAl-QadriSabil You should read up on `EXISTS`, because it is a core part of the SQL language, and it can be very powerful.  My query basically says take every row in your April-June 2018 date range, so long as we _can't_ find a record for the same buyer, which is outside of that range.  The `SELECT 1` is arbitrary, is could just as easily be `SELECT 'cat'`.